# How to pass values from datagridview1 to datagridview2 with existing values?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to pass values from one datagridview to another datagridview...

But the values should keep on adding... like a stack...

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
    {
        string ID, ItemCode, ProductName, Amount, qty = comboBox2.Text,Total;

        ID = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "";
        ItemCode = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "";
        ProductName = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value + "";
        Amount = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
        Total = (Convert.ToInt32(Amount) * Convert.ToInt32(qty)).ToString();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(ID, ItemCode, ProductName,Total);

       if (dataGridView2.RowCount > 0)
        {
            string a, b, c, d;
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            a = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "";
            b = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "";
            c = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value + "";
            d = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
            table1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table1.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
            table1.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
            table1.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
            table1.Rows.Add(a, b, c, d);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = table1;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = table;                        
        }
        else
        {
        dataGridView2.DataSource = table;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without analysing the code detailed I must say I'm confused by the 2 lines dataGridView2.DataSource = table1; and dataGridView2.DataSource = table; You first bind the data source to 1 table and then you bind it to another table so you overwrite the DataSource. I think you want to create a table that merges values from both tables and then bind the DataSource to this merged table ?

Comment: exactly... the idea is i need to pass the values from dgv1 to dgv 2, but in dgv 2 the values overwrites the existing values...

Comment: Have you tried this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 gridviews with same column names you could do something as like,

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
        {
            string ID, ItemCode, ProductName, Amount, qty = comboBox2.Text, Total;

            ID = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value + "";
            ItemCode = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "";
            ProductName = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value + "";
            Amount = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
            Total = (Convert.ToInt32(Amount) * Convert.ToInt32(qty)).ToString();

            DataTable table;

            if (dataGridView2.RowCount > 0)
            {
                table = (DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource;
            }
            else
            {
                table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
            }
            table.Rows.Add(ID, ItemCode, ProductName, Total);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it works... thank you so much... was searching for like 12 hours or more... you are the best!!!... is there anyway i could repay this favour???